batch for update entities list by NamedQuery and function with Pair as input
I've found very interesting but not implemented method in some CoreDao Interface:
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import javax.management.Query;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;


public interface CoreDao<R> {
    <R> void batchUpdateNamedQuery(String namedQueryName, List<R> updatedEntities, Function<Pair<R,Query>, Query> updater);
}

so, populate the implementation method body seems quite easy, after injecting EntityManager:
updatedEntities.stream().forEach({ ent ->
Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQueryName);
updater.apply(Pair.of(ent, query).executeUpdate();
})

but what functional programming example could be implemented as updater? Any idea for Pair as the input to the function?
